# How to replace string values with "XXXXX" in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I want to replace particular string values with "XXXX". The issue is the pattern is very dynamic and it won't have a fixed pattern in input data.

My input data

> https://internetbanking.abc.co.uk/personal/logon/login/?userId=Templ3108&password=Got1&reme

I need to replace the values of userId and password with "XXXX".

My output should be -

> https://internetbanking.abc.co.uk/personal/logon/login/?userId=XXXX&password=XXXX&reme

This is an one off example. There are other cases where only userId and password is present -

> userId=12345678&password=stackoverflow&rememberID=

I am using Regex in java to achieve the above, but have not been successful yet. Appreciate any guidance.

```
[&]([^\\/?&;]{0,})(userId=|password=)=[^&;]+|((?<=\\/)|(?<=\\?)|(?<=;))([^\\/?&;]{0,})(userId=|password=)=[^&]+|(?<=\\?)(userId=|password=)=[^&]+|(userId=|password=)=[^&]+
```

PS : I am not an expert in Regex. Also, please do let me know if there are any other alternatives to achieve this apart from Regex.

Comment: Who ever sends passwords over GET should be fired. Also, there is no need to regex this stuff, just use common string operations like indexOf and replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
String url = "https://internetbanking.abc.co.uk/personal/logon/login/?userId=Templ3108&password=Got1&reme";
String masked = url.replaceAll("(userId|password)=[^&]+", "$1=XXXX");
```

See [online demo](https://regexr.com/4vd87) and [regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Ex3pku/1).

Please note, that **[sending sensitive data via the query string is a big security issue](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/should-sensitive-data-ever-be-passed-in-the-query-string)**.

Comment: This will also replace string like authorizeduserId=... or similar with password.

Comment: @DavidAmar `replaceAll("([?&])(userId|password)=[^&]+", "$1$2=XXXX")` would fix that, but I'm not sure it's necessary in this case; especially when you notice that `authorizeduserId` would propably be `authorizedUserId` (note uppercase `U`); and even if there was `authorizeduserId`, it's probably something you want to mask. Good catch anyway - Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This may cover given both cases.

```
String maskUserNameAndPassword(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("(userId|password)=[^&]+", "$1=XXXXX");
}

String inputUrl1 = 
    "https://internetbanking.abc.co.uk/personal/logon/login/?userId=Templ3108&password=Got1&reme";

String inputUrl2 = 
    "userId=12345678&password=stackoverflow&rememberID=";

String input = "https://internetbanking.abc.co.uk/personal/logon/login/?userId=Templ3108&password=Got1&reme";

String maskedUrl1 = maskUserNameAndPassword(inputUrl1);
System.out.println("Mask url1: " + maskUserNameAndPassword(inputUrl1));

String maskedUrl2 = maskUserNameAndPassword(inputUrl1);
System.out.println("Mask url2: " + maskUserNameAndPassword(inputUrl2));
```

Above will result:

```
Mask url1: https://internetbanking.abc.co.uk/personal/logon/login/?userId=XXXXX&password=XXXXX&reme
Mask url2: userId=XXXXX&password=XXXXX&rememberID=
```

Comment: what if password or userId values contains some URL-escaped text?

Comment: Then, you apply URL decode first and then mask userId and password.
`java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: And then what? You re-URL-encode it afterwards to leave other values unchanged? wouldn’t it be more simple to change the \w by something more accurate ? Also, what if decoded password contains chars like @ or $? Fixing \w kills two birds with one stone

Comment: Yeah true, better to improve \w to support special characters.

Comment: Found what @TeWu has proposed here.
It may cover most of the cases than `\w`.
But assuming `userId` or `password` not allow `&` character within it.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use a URL parser than regex. The below example uses the standard URL class available in java but third party libraries can do it much better.

```
Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, Map.Entry<String, String>> maskUserPasswordEntries = e ->
        (e.getKey().equals("userId") || e.getKey().equals("password")) ? Map.entry(e.getKey(), "XXXX") : e;
Function<List<String>, Map.Entry<String, String>> transformParamsToMap = p ->
        Map.entry(p.get(0), p.size() == 1 ? "" : p.get(p.size() - 1));

URL url = new URL("https://internetbanking.abc.co.uk/personal/logon/login/?userId=Templ3108&password=Got1&reme");
String maskedQuery = Stream.of(url.getQuery().split("&"))
        .map(s -> List.of(s.split("=")))
        .map(transformParamsToMap)
        .map(maskUserPasswordEntries).map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
System.out.println(url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getAuthority() + url.getPath() + "?" + maskedQuery);
```

Output:

```
https://internetbanking.abc.co.uk/personal/logon/login/?userId=XXXX&password=XXXX&reme=
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
(?<=(\?|&))(userId|password)=(.*?)(?=(&|$))
```

- `(?<=(\?|&))` makes sure it’s preceded by `?` or `&` (but not part of the match)
- `(userId|password)=` matches either `userId` or `password`, then `=`
- `(.*?)` matches any char as long as the next instruction cannot be executed
- `(?=(&|$))` makes sure the next char is either `&` or end of the string, (but not part of the match)

Then, replace with `$2=xxxxx` (to keep `userId` or `password`) and choose `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the methods replace/replaceAll from the String class, they support Charset aswell as regex.

```
String url = "https://internetbanking.abc.co.uk/personal/logon/login/?userId=Templ3108&password=Got1&reme";

url = url.replaceAll("(userId=.+?&)", "userId=XXXX&");
url = url.replaceAll("(password=.+?&)", "password=XXXX&");

System.out.println(url);
```

I'm not a regex expert either, but if you find it useful, I usually use this website to test my expressions and as a online Cheatsheet:

https://regexr.com